# Ping problems discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, ping

https://gyazo.com/fce96f41aee0160e197981d1646600a2

```
bot.on('message', msg=> { 
    if(msg.content == "ping"){ 
            msg.reply("Asteapta...") 
            .then((msg) => { // Resolve promise
                msg.edit("> Pingul este: " + (Date.now() - msg.createdTimestamp)+" milisecunde") // Edits message with current timestamp minus timestamp of message
            });
        }
})
```

As you see in the video, The ping is showing negative and as a big number. Help please!

Answer (score 1):

If the Date.now() is greater than the msg.createdTimestamp it will give a negative number.

```
Date.now() - (Date.now() + 1400) = -1400
```

Change it to the reverse:

```
(Date.now() + 1400) - Date.now() = 1400
```

Your code changed:

```
(msg.createdTimestamp - Date.now())
```